# Resetting css attributes after third submenu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list, html-lists

I have a Wordpress menu with 5 sub-menus. Something like:

- Item 1

  - Item 2

    - Item 3

      - Item 4

        - Item 5

          - Item 6
- Item 1
- Item 1
- Item 1

and I'm using css to add some style. The problem is, when I do something like:

```
ul { padding: 10px; }
```

it adds this rule to every item, but I want to add it to only two first "ul" tags. I know that i can do:

```
ul, ul ul { padding:10px;}
ul ul ul { padding:initial !important }
```

but is there a better solution to do that?

Comment: You can do it by  using class `ul.style-ul { padding:10px;}` where there is css class style-ul in ul .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use direct children selector `>`:

```
ul:first-child,ul>ul{padding: 10px;}
```

But I would like to recommend you to use a common class for them and use padding in them:

```
ul.pd10{padding: 10px;}
```

Comment: So if I want to add style to first four ul tags it will be something like: `ul ul ul > ul {padding: 10px;}` ?

Comment: that's why it is better to use a common class for them